# How can I calculate the distance to the nearest five neighbors for a polygon layer?

Tags: qgis, distance

Data set (shapefile) contains polygons.  How can I calculate the distance to the nearest five polygons in the data set in QGIS?

Comment: dataset is a shapefile?

Comment: how you want to measure the distance? Is it centroid to centroid? Closest vertices? Shortest line between edges?

Comment: shortest line between edges

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do this, using postgresql and qgis. It finds the closest 5 polygons to each polygon in the dataset. The screenshot should show how it establishes distances.

[image: N nearest polygons]

> Note that I'm using British National Grid (27700) - this a local UTM
>   projection in meters, so over these relatively short distances the
>   results will be quite accurate. You'll need to project your data into
>   a similar CRS for your locale. If you're using longer distances - such
>   as between countries or regions - you'll need to use **::geography**.

- imported polygons from OpenStreetMap into PostgreSQL using **shp2pgsql**. This tool also sets up spatial indexes to speed things up.
- ran the query below
- exported to CSV, then imported as delimited layer
- set CRS of new layer to my local projection (27700)

Query:-

```
select * from (
    select
        a.gid as from_gid, -- this is an ID created on import
        b.gid as to_gid, 
        a.full_id as from_originalid, -- this was original unique ID in shapefile
        b.full_id as to_originalid,
        st_asewkt(st_shortestline(a.geom,b.geom)), 
        st_distance(a.geom,b.geom) as distance,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.gid ORDER BY st_distance(a.geom,b.geom)) as rk
    from
        my_table as a,
        my_table as b
    where 
        st_dwithin(a.geom,b.geom,4000) and a.gid!=b.gid -- must be < 4km
    group by
        a.gid, 
        b.gid
    order by
        a.gid,
        st_distance(a.geom,b.geom) ASC
) as res
where rk<=5 -- how many neighbours you want
```

Now, I have a table which links each patch to its 5 closest neighbours...

```
"from_gid","to_gid","from_originalid","to_originalid","?column?","distance","rk"
1,90,"w33458756","w233167579","geometry",0.8228431343271,1
1,91,"w33458756","w233167992","geometry",21.1914264821244,2
1,92,"w33458756","w233168011","geometry",44.5356828699015,3
1,88,"w33458756","w233167212","geometry",86.986670207639,4
1,89,"w33458756","w233167528","geometry",109.008710565124,5
2,140,"w33458843","w307855181","geometry",41.0315108912926,1
2,11,"w33458843","w232374434","geometry",123.281434892635,2
2,10,"w33458843","w232373705","geometry",184.603505248759,3
...etc...
```

Note that the **st_dwithin()** is used to speed up the query. This means that if a line is longer than 4km, it's not used. You'll need to tweak that for your dataset.